# Rails/Centos7 - ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, centos7

I got this error message when trying to install rails on Centos 7.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Command

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.3 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri is causing you problems. Installing all the build dependencies and try again.

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel make
```

If it still fails, try to build it with the `--use-system-libraries` build option.

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

If all else fails, install it from the EPEL repository.

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri
```